# Theorem 7.17 in Baby Rudin: Differentiability of the limit function of a uniformly convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Here is a theorem which I came across in **Principles of Mathematical analysis** by Walter Rudin

> **Theorem 7.17$\space\space$** Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$ and such that $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges for some point $x_0$ on $[a,b].$ If $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then ${f_n}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, to a function $f$, and $$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'_n(x)\quad\quad\quad\quad(a\le x\le b)$$

In the proof of this theorem he proves the uniform convergence of ${f_n}$ and defines the limit function as equal to $f$. Further he says that if we fix a point $x$ then we can define $$\phi_n(t)=\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x},\quad\quad\quad \phi(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$$ for $a\le t\le b,\space t\neq x$. It is then proven that $\phi_n(t)$ converges uniformly for $t\neq x$ using the Cauchy criterion of uniform convergence which means that the proof of $\phi_n(t)$ is uniformly convergent has been established but the limit function is yet unknown. He then writes that since $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ therefore we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(t)=\phi(t)$$
It is this part of the proof which I don't understand. If we are claiming that $\phi_n(t)$ converges uniformly to $\phi(t)$ then it should be possible to show that for an $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $N$ such that $\quad sup|\phi_n(t)-\phi(t)|\lt\varepsilon\quad$ for all $n\ge N$ if $t\in[a,b],$ and $t\neq x$. The way I started to prove it is

$$|\phi_n(t)-\phi(t)|=\left|\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}-\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\right|\le 
\frac{1}{|t-x|} \Bigl[|f_n(t)-f(t)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|\Bigr]$$
If I resolve the above I will be able to show the existence of an $N$ such that
$$|\phi_n(t)-\phi(t)| \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{|t-x|}$$
for all $n\ge N$. So, how do I get rid of $|t-x|$ in the above since I can't assume that $f$ is differentiable (that is what we have to prove in this theorem) so mean value theorem is out of question?

Another doubt in the same proof has already been asked here: [Baby Rudin Theorem 7.17](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416154/theorem-7-17-in-baby-rudin-how-is-a-shorter-proof-possible-if-the-continuity-of) where the whole proof has been quoted from the book. Since I don't have enough reputation yet so I couldn't ask for clarification of the proof in the same thread itself and hence have to post it as a separate question.

Comment: As $f_n(t),f_n(x)$ and $\phi_n(t):=\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}$ all converge, passing to the limit (in the definition of $\phi_n(t)$) gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$, and this happens to be the definition of $\phi(t)$.

Comment: Yes, but the way I was approaching it, there should be a way to do it that way as well, right? We should be able to show that it is smaller than an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ for all $t\in[a,b],\space t\neq x$

Comment: You know that $\{\phi_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E:=[a,b]\setminus\{x\}$ using the Cauchy criterion. Also, we know in particular that $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[a,b]$ (by definition of $f$), and thus basic limit properties tell us $\phi_n\to \phi$ pointwise on $E$. But we already know that $\{\phi_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E$, so actually, $\phi_n\to \phi$ uniformly on $E$. It seems like you want to show directly that $\phi_n\to \phi$ uniformly on $E$; but this completely ignores the utility of the Cauchy criterion. Certainly doable, but why bother?

Comment: If you want to supersede the use of Cauchy's criterion, I am guessing you would still need to use a completeness argument somewhere, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, one could avoid an explicit usage of the Cauchy criterion by intertwining it into a complicated estimate (i.e basically repeat proofs of theorems already proven). Just to be clear: I think Rudin's proof is going to be much simpler than what I present below, but in case you're a brave soul, here goes.

Let $\psi$ be the limit of $f_n'$. I'm going to assume we already know $f_n$ converges pointwise to some function $f$. Now, fix an $x\in [a,b]$. Now, for any $t\neq x$, and any $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$, we use a 3-fold triangle inequality to get
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|&\leq
\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}\right|\\
&+\left|\frac{(f_n-f_m)(t)-(f_n-f_m)(x)}{t-x}\right|\\
&+\left|\frac{f_m(t)-f_m(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|
\end{align}
Using the mean-value theorem for $f_n-f_m$, we can bound the second term by $\|f_n'-f_m'\|_{\infty}$ (i.e the supremum norm). Hence, we get
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|&\leq
\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}\right|\\
&+\|f_n'-f_m'\|_{\infty}\\
&+\left|\frac{f_m(t)-f_m(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|
\end{align}
Now, we take the limit as $n\to \infty$ on both sides. On the LHS, nothing happens, while on the RHS, the first term vanishes since $f_n\to f$ pointwise by definition. The second term becomes $\|\psi-f_m'\|_{\infty}$ (because norms are continuous so we can pull the limit inside. Note that we're using the fact $f_n'\to \psi$ uniformly here). Hence,
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right| & \leq 0 + \|\psi-f_m'\|_{\infty}+
\left|\frac{f_m(t)-f_m(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|
\end{align}
Now, we take $\limsup\limits_{t\to x}$ on both sides (we take $\limsup$ because the limit superior of any function always exists, while the limit a-priori need not exist. Also, recall that limit exists if and only if $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are equal, in which case all three are equal). This gives us
\begin{align}
\limsup_{t\to x}\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right| & \leq \|\psi-f_m'\|_{\infty}+\limsup_{t\to x}\left|\frac{f_m(t)-f_m(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|\\
&=\|\psi-f_m'\|_{\infty}+|f_m'(x)-\psi(x)|\\
&\leq 2\|f_m'-\psi\|_{\infty}.
\end{align}
Finally, we can let $m\to \infty$, so that the RHS vanishes. Therefore, we have proven that
\begin{align}
\limsup_{t\to x}\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-\psi(x)\right|&\leq 0.
\end{align}
This means the $\limsup$ is actually equal to $0$, and thus the $\lim\limits_{t\to x}$ also exists and equals zero. This is exactly what it means to show $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with $f'(x)=\psi(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n'(x)$.

The usefulness of $\limsup$ is that it saves us from bringing in $\epsilon$'s and $N$'s and $\delta$'s.

Comment: If you do not mind me asking, the problem at the core is that I am not able to convince myself of the following line of argument.

Comment: If ${f_n}$ is uniform convergent on $[a,b]$ to $f$ then $\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}$ will also be uniformly convergent to $\frac{f(x)-f(t)}{t-x}$ for $ t\in [a,b] \setminus \{x\}$. Because if it is then we should be able to show the existence of an $N$ such that $\left| \frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}-\frac{f(x)-f(t)}{t-x}\right|\lt \varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Even if we use the basic limit theorem how do I arrive at this **particular** inequality?

Comment: Let's say that there was no $|t-x|$ in denominator then can we show that $|f_n(t)-f(t) -f_n(x)+f(x)|\lt \varepsilon\space|t-x|$ since $f_n$ and $f$ are both continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @SilentDissent do you agree that Rudin has already shown $\{\phi_n\}$ converges uniformly to **some** function on $E=[a,b]\setminus\{x\}$?

Comment: Yes, I understood his proof that $\{\phi_n\}$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: @SilentDissent ok that's step 1. Let us call that "some" function $\theta:E\to\Bbb{R}$. The next step is the following. We know that $f_n\to f$ pointwise (in fact uniformly, but here we only need pointwise). Thus, pointwise, we have $\phi_n(t)=\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}\to \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\phi(t)$. Since pointwise limits are unique, we must have $\theta=\phi$. But by step 1, we know $\phi_n$ converges uniformly to $\theta$, which is $\phi$ by step 2. Conclusion: $\phi_n\to \phi$ uniformly on $E$.

Comment: Okay, even if $f_n$ is pointwise convergent to $f$ then how can we say that $\phi_n$ must also be pointwise convergent to $\phi$? How are we sure that there doesn't exist a $t\in [a,b]\setminus \{x\}$ for which $|\phi_n(t) - \phi(t)| \ge \varepsilon$ no matter what value of $n$ we take?

Comment: @SilentDissent this is basic limit properties (subtraction, scalar multiplication etc etc). $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[a,b]$ means for any $t\in E=[a,b]\setminus\{x\}$, we have $f_n(t)\to f(t)$, and also $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and thus $f_n(t)-f_n(x)\to f(t)-f(x)$ and thus $\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}\to \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$; i.e $\phi_n(t)\to \phi(t)$. These are all theorems stated very early on in Rudin.

Comment: If you really want me to write out an $\epsilon, N$ proof here it is. Fix $t\in E$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, there exist $N_t\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N_t$, we have $|f_n(t)-f(t)|< \frac{\epsilon|t-x|}{2}$. Likewise, there exists $N_x\in\Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N_x$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon |t-x|}{2}$. Thus, for any $n\geq \max(N_t,N_x)$, we have $\left|\frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}-\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\right|\leq\frac{|f_n(t)-f(t)|}{|t-x|}+\frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{|t-x|}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129279/discussion-between-silent-dissent-and-peek-a-boo).