# Show that the following series is well defined and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Show that for every a, b ∈ $ \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$ with $a < 1$ and $ab < 1$ that the following function is well defined and differentiable: $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}a^n\cos(b^n \pi x) $$

I noticed this is a variant of the Weierstrass function but with $ab < 1$. I don't really know where to start, I have tried using the limit definition of a derivative but that doesn't really get me anywhere. Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to use uniform convergence? it may be helpful

Comment: No, not yet. I haven't thought of that, I'll try that, thanks!!

Comment: look at this theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241569/theorem-7-17-in-baby-rudin-differentiability-of-the-limit-function-of-a-uniform